# scala.MatchError: 0.13.0 (of class java.lang.String)

Tags: scala, sbt

I am getting this error "scala.MatchError: 0.13.0 (of class java.lang.String)" while setting up sbt on Mac. Is there any steps I might be missing.

Comment: can you provide the source? it might be non exhaustive?

Comment: Found out that brew install sbt
Warning: You have not agreed to the Xcode license.
Builds will fail! Agree to the license by opening Xcode.app or running:
    xcodebuild -license
Warning: sbt-0.13.0 already installed.... I just opened the Xcode app and agreed and then it started working....thanks for your help..

Comment: Could you close the question, or provide the answer please? Otherwise it'll keep showing up as unanswered.

Comment: I think I have to wait 48 hours to close it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builds will fail! Agree to the license by opening Xcode.app or running: xcodebuild -license Warning: sbt-0.13.0 already installed.... I just opened the Xcode app and agreed and then it started working.